# shift columns of a dataframe without looping?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

consider this toy example.  i need to shift each column down by one * (its position in the array).  so a kind of diagonal shift:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(5,5)),columns=list("ABCDE"))

for i,k in enumerate(df):
    df[k] = df[k].shift(i)
```

transforms:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  6  1  6  3  1
1  2  7  5  9  7
2  6  6  6  9  8
3  7  8  8  2  8
4  5  2  9  9  2
```

into

```
   A   B   C   D   E
0  6 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  2   1 NaN NaN NaN
2  6   7   6 NaN NaN
3  7   6   5   3 NaN
4  5   8   6   9   1
```

which is what i want.

however for larger dataframes with hierarchical indexes, this looping method does not seem feasible.  in fact, i've got an ipython notebook that has been running for almost an hour now with no end in sight.

this makes me think that there must be an easier, perhaps vectorized way...  perhaps using some kind of "apply", however i'm not sure how to do that when each column needs to be shifted down as a function of its position in the array.

Comment: Apply still uses loops by the way

Comment: I don't think it's possible to vectorize operations across columns, since columns (like the fields in a numpy `recarray`) are effectively separate `ndarrays` that may have heterogeneous `dtypes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have really a lot of data (dozens of gigabytes), shifting it does not take hours. It seems that the time is spent in rebuilding the indices. Especially with hierarchical indexing it is possible that the complex indices are rebuilt after each shift. If your tables are large, this may take a lot of time.

One possible approach (at least to isolate the problem) is to just extract the data into a `np.array` (take the `.values`), shift it, and recreate the DataFrame. In `numpy` shifting the data is rather trivial by, e.g.:

```
for c in range(1, a.shape[1]):
    a[c:,c] = a[:-c,c]
    a[:c, c] = np.nan
```

Shifting a float array with 500 columns and a million rows (4 GB array) with this code took my computer approximately 12 seconds, but the total time will depend heavily on your indexing and the cost of recreating it.

Comment: thank you.  it seems as though i was not looping through my hierarchical columns correctly.